# DISTINCT with CAST and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct, sql-server-express

I'm trying to get a `DISTINCT` of the column `FeedbackDT` but i can't seem to figure why doesn't it work..

SQL Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(FeedbackID) as FeedbackID,
       (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(feedbackDateTime AS DATE)) as FeedbackDT
FROM Feedback
WHERE feedBackDateTime <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY (feedbackDateTime)
```

The result of the executed query

[image]

I searched high and low but to no avail..

Appreciate any help, thanks..

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. And not too many rows. Both table data and the expected result!

Comment: @jarlh i'm using SQL Server Management Studio / SQLExpress

Comment: please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/57475)

Comment: you guys don't have to downvote it lol. Not to be rude, but sometimes i don't get the mentality of some people here. i'd rather show the entire thing than to give viewers insufficient information, some may or may not know what's going on.

Comment: @domster Use the site properly and you won't get downvotes. Why is that a "mentality" issue of anyone but yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your current query doesn't make much sense. When you use `GROUP BY`, you get the distinct values of the column you are grouping by (or the combination of columns, if you are using more than one). There's no need for the `SELECT DISTINCT` subquery that you are using.

It seems to me that you need to use a simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CAST(feedbackDateTime AS DATE) FeedbackDT,
       COUNT(FeedbackID) as FeedbackID
FROM Feedback
WHERE feedBackDateTime <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY CAST(feedbackDateTime AS DATE)
;
```

Comment: Hey Lamak, sweet! I get what you mean.. I guess i made myself confuse.. Appreciate the help, thanks! It's working now! Will mark as answer in a few.. Cheers!